# Springboot application Add pie chart to an email template using thymeleaf (Sending email with charts in Spring with Thymeleaf)

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Following this link for reference: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

I am using Thymeleaf for generating html content to be sent in an email report. In addition to the html, I want to include a pie chart.

Below is the html template:

Is it possible to add pie chart to the email template? Any examples on how to do it? Thanks!
This pie chart needs to be sent in the email.

```
<div>
    <label><b>Job Name:</b></label>
<span th:text="${data.job.name}"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <label><b>Environment:</b></label>
    <span th:text="${data.job.env}"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <label><b>Fail | Pass | Total Count:</b></label>
    <span th:text="${data.build.failCount}"></span>&nbsp&nbsp<span th:text="${data.build.passCount}"></span>&nbsp&nbsp<span th:text="${data.build.totalCount}"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <label><b>App Issues | Test Failures | Env Issues | Infra Issue QE | Other issues</b></label>
    <span th:text="${data.appIssues}"></span>%&nbsp&nbsp<span th:text="${data.testFailures}"></span>%&nbsp&nbsp
    <span th:text="${data.environmentIssues}"></span>%&nbsp&nbsp</span><span th:text="${data.infraIssuesQE}"></span>
    <span th:text="${data.thirdPartyIssues}"></span>%&nbsp&nbsp</span><span th:text="${data.otherIssues}"></span>%&nbsp&nbsp
</div>

<div>
    <label><b>Build No:</b></label>
    <a th:href="${data.build.url}"><span th:text="${data.build.buildNo}"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Any one? Does thymeleaf template support charts?

Comment: Were you able to implement this ? I saw some examples with google charts, that will work with thymeleaf, but uses javascript, which will obv not work on most email clients.

Comment: any luck? I'm looking for the same thing.